# Get contents of <h1> convert them it to text and set as a title of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got following structure of `h1` element

```
<h1>
<a href="#">My Text</a> <span>More Text</span> another text <a href="#">and a bit more</a>
</h1>
```

How can I get contents from such `h1` and convert them to text so the output would be `"My Text More Text another text and a bit more"`

and after that place it into the `<title>` of the page? So no links, spans etc.. Just text?

Comment: `var text = "textContent" in document ? "textContent" : "innerText"; document.title = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0][text];`

Comment: @Ian 40 wish this were an answer. Here's a virtual +1!

Comment: @Ian Would you like to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With jQuery it's just:

```
$('title').text($('h1').text());
```

Answer (score 9):

Without jQuery, you can access the `<h1>`'s `textContent` property (`innerText` in old IE), and you can change `document.title` (like modifying the `<title></title>`). Here's an example:

```
var text = "textContent" in document.body ? "textContent" : "innerText";
document.title = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0][text];
```

Depending on how you want to target the `<h1>`, you can change the `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]`.

Also, I'm not sure how it affects the `title`, but the whitespace before the first `<a>` and after the last `</a>` will be included unless you `trim` the string. So maybe turn it into:

```
function trim(s) {
    if (typeof s === "string") {
        s = s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    }
    return s;
}

var el = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0],
    text = "textContent" in el ? "textContent" : "innerText";
document.title = trim(el[text]);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tzGzC/

Of course, with just jQuery, it's a lot simpler:

```
var el = $("h1").eq(0),
    text = el.text();
document.title = $.trim(text);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kMXLW/

**References:**

- `document.title`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.title
- `.textContent`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Comment: This should have been the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var h1content = document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML;
// stripped string taken from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/
var newTitle = h1content.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
document.title = newTitle;
```

Something to note, crawlers do NOT follow Javascript code, meaning that although this will change the title of the page, it will not be Search Engine Optimized.

Comment: Simple solution, but generally [not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Doesn't this assume the `<h1>` tag has an ID of "h1"?